# Configure angular $http with a value obtained from server

Tags: angularjs, session, angular-http-interceptors

I'm building my (first) angular app that will have tokens inserted into headers (the content shown is for the most part taken from [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/))

angular.module('myApp')

```
.factory('sessionInjector', ['SessionService', function(SessionService) {  
   var sessionInjector = {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers['x-session-token'] = SessionService.getToken();
            return config;
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}])

.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}])
```

The trouble I'm having is with `SessionService` - how can I initialize this with call to the server?

For example, this didn't work:

```js
.factory('SessionService', ['$injector', function($injector){
    var token = "";

    return {
        getToken: function () {
            var http = $injector.get('$http');
            if (token === "") {
                http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/getToken').success(function (ret) {
                    token = ret;
                });
            }
            return token; 
            //I can see a $q/deferred/promise should be used somehow here... 
            //but I'm not sure it solves the problem I'm having...
        }
    }
}]);
```

because it just overloads my cpu to 100%...

Since it's my first angular app, I'm sure I'm missing something, but... what?

**EDIT**:
Another take on the matter... still doesn't work though... (again, uses up cpu, probably infinite loop)

```js
  .factory('sessionData', function () {
    var currentToken = '[uninitialized-token]';

    return {
        getToken: function () {
            return currentToken;
        },
        setToken: function (token) {
            currentToken = token;
        }
    }
})

.factory('sessionInjector', ['sessionData', '$injector', '$q', function (sessionData, $injector, $q) {
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function (config) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var http = $injector.get('$http');
            http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/getToken').success(function (ret) {
                sessionData.setToken(ret);
                console.log("successfully authenticated with token " + sessionData.getToken());
                config.headers['x-header-sessionID'] = sessionData.getToken();
                deferred.resolve(config);
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("failed to authenticate");
                deferred.resolve(config);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}])

.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}])

.run(['$http', 'sessionData', function ($http, configs, sessionData) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/testMethod').then(function (ret) {
        //do something...
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was actually pretty straight forward - if the targeted URL is for login, then don't inject anything (look for the comment `the fix`):

```
.factory('sessionData', function () {
    var currentToken = '[uninitialized-token]';

    return {
        getToken: function () {
            return currentToken;
        },
        setToken: function (token) {
            currentToken = token;
        }
    }
})

.factory('sessionInjector', ['sessionData', '$injector', '$q', function (sessionData, $injector, $q) {
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function (config) {

            //The fix:
            if(config.url === 'http://localhost/api/auth/getToken')
                return config;

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var http = $injector.get('$http');
            http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/getToken').success(function (ret) {
                sessionData.setToken(ret);
                console.log("successfully authenticated with token " + sessionData.getToken());
                config.headers['x-header-sessionID'] = sessionData.getToken();
                deferred.resolve(config);
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("failed to authenticate");
                deferred.resolve(config);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}])

.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}])

.run(['$http', 'sessionData', function ($http, configs, sessionData) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/testMethod').then(function (ret) {
        //do something...
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this modified code fragment will solve your issues.

```
.factory('SessionService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var token = null;
    var sessionService = {};
    var differred = $q.defer();

    sessionService.readToken = function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/getToken')
            .success(function (res) {
                console.log('Auth Success and token received: ' + JSON.stringify(res.data));

                // Extract the token details from the received JSON object
                token = res.data;
                differred.resolve(res);
            }, function (res) {
                console.log('Error occurred : ' + JSON.stringify(res));
                differred.reject(res);
            }
        )
    };

    sessionService.getToken = function() {
        return token;
    };

    sessionService.isAnonymous = function() {
        if (token)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    return sessionService;
}])


.factory('sessionInjector', ['SessionService', function(SessionService) {
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function(config) {
            if (!sessionService.isAnonymous) {
                config.headers['x-session-token'] = SessionService.getToken();
                return config;
            }
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}])

.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but it doesn't work. The $http you're using isn't injected. And even if it was it would create circular reference and wouldn't work. That's why I had to get the $http from $injector in time of the request for token (inside a function, under it's context at runtime when requested)...

Comment: There was a typo in the Session service declaration which corrected. Moreover, first you need to call the `Session.readToken()` method inside your controller to read it. Afterwards, if token available all consecutive requests will be dispatched with the token as a HTTP header parameter. This is working and tested. No circular references were observed, in the way I defined it.

Comment: This is the circular error I'm getting when I used your code: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- SessionService <- sessionInjector <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile` (AngularJS v1.4.3)

Comment: Could you prepare a Plunker for this.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vqTB0q?p=preview , I don't see a way to view the javascript console ... when you put code locally, you'd get the errors in the console...